# Why can't i ping the @everyone discord role?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a function that writes news to discord, it pings everyone. To ping everyone, I write `ctx.send(...)`, if I write `ctx.response.send_message(...)`, then @everyone does not work [@everyone not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StdaF.png). And I need to somehow remove ctx.response

```
@commands.slash_command(name="news",description="news")
    async def news(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, title, news):
        if ctx.author.top_role.name not in settings['high_admin_role']:
            await ctx.response.send_message("not permission",ephemeral=True)
            return
        else:
            news = ''.join(news).replace(';', '\n')
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"""{title}""", description=f"""{news}\n\nОт: {ctx.author.mention}""", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(199, 135, 24))
            await ctx.send('||@everyone||', embed=embed)
```

I tried ctx.defer(), ctx.response.defer(). I tried to send messages via response, but then @everyone doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here why the role `@everyone` doesn't receive the ping could have 2 reasons:

- **Missing Bot-rights:** Maybe your bot is missing the `MENTION EVERYONE` permission in the `channel`, where you're sending your message - that is **probably your issue** here.
- **Mention the role like it should be:** The way you're trying to mention the `@everyone` role is not wrong, but maybe it is bugged in your discord library. So you could try the official way to mention the role.

The official way to mention the `@everyone` role is to get the `guild.default_role` object first and then mention that object itself. That works like this:

- `await ctx.send(f'||{ctx.guild.default_role.mention}||', embed=embed)`

If that is not working too, your bot is cleary missing the right `MENTION EVERYONE` in your discord channel. You can change that if you edit the channel permissions and turn that on (**ONLY FOR YOUR BOT**):

---

If that all **doesn't help you** (which would be weird behaivor), you could try to use `discord.AllowedMentions`:

```py
allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=True)
await ctx.send(f'||{ctx.guild.default_role.mention}||', embed=embed, allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
```

Comment: everyone works for me if I write ctx.send. I tried ctx.guild.default_role.mention, but it didn't help. The bot has rights, he is an administrator and additionally granted rights to everyone. I use py-cord

Comment: Maybe its because of the spoiler you're using (the `||` symbols), try it without them.

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: i edited my answer and added discord.AllowedMentions, try that out.

Comment: oh yes it helped, thank you. I still don't understand why it didn't work before, the bot has all the rights and Intents.all()

Comment: Is it possible to somehow grant these rights separately, so as not to write it in each function?

Comment: What "rights" do you mean?

Comment: discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=True)

Comment: I guess that's not possible. But you can define that at the top of every function, which would make it possible to create it just one time in every function.